# Python JSON: raise JSONDecodeError from parse_constant

Tags: python, json, jsondecodeerror

I am currently using the `json` module to load some JSON content and I need to exclude NaN values. The standard way to do this seems to be to implement a `parse_constant` method and then pass this method to `json.loads`.

Example:

```py
def parse_constant(c: str) -> float:
    if c == "NaN":
        raise ValueError("NaN is not valid JSON")
    return float(c)

json_content = json.loads(some_json_string, parse_constant=parse_constant)
```

Apparently, the decode implementation does not catch the `ValueError` and transform it into a `JSONDecodeError`, which forces me to check for both exception types. I miss the context (line number, JSON document) to build the decode error myself. I know I could just catch `ValueError`, but is there a way to configure the `json` module to raise what I would expect to be the logical exception type?

Comment: Maybe you need another json module? [`orjson`](https://github.com/ijl/orjson) for instance. With `'{"x": 1, "y": NaN}'` it would return: "orjson.JSONDecodeError: unexpected character: line 1 column 15 (char 14)"

Comment: I'm planning to try `orjson` soon. Nonetheless, I'm curious to see if this is somehow possible with the default `json` module.